# Structure query based on doc field and embedded doc field while returning embedded doc

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database

I'm trying to query a mongo database for an embedded document. I'm querying based on a field in the document and a field in the embedded document.

Here's an example with a couple of documents.

**doc 1**

```
{
  token: 'foo'
  services: [
  {
    service: 'one',
    data: {...}
  },
  {
    service: 'two',
    data: {...}
  }
  ]
}
```

**doc 2**

```
{
  token: 'bar'
  services: [
  {
    service: 'one',
    data: {...}
  },
  {
    service: 'two',
    data: {...}
  }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to get the `{service: 'one', data: {...}}` embedded doc from the first document. However I'm not quite sure how to structure the query. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a collection as such:

```
   var coll =  {
      token: 'foo',
      services: [
        {
          service: 'one',
          data: {}
        },
        {
          service: 'two',
          data: {}
        }
      ]
    }
```

You can access the `service: 'one'` object using: `coll.services[0]` query.

**Updated**
If you want to select object by field, you can try this:

```
$.grep(coll.services, function(e) { return e.service == 'one' });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, this won't work as I can't specify by array index, I need to specify by field.

Comment: Is $.grep mongodb syntax or are you referring to jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

If doc 1 and doc 2 represent two documents in the same collection, then you need to get the first document by some clear identifier like id or name etc, and then read the first element of the services array from your code.

If doc 1 and doc 2 are the results of a query and you need to filter the documents that match {service: 'one', data: {...}} then because services is an array, you need to use $elemMatch.

```
coll.find( { services : { $elemMatch : { service : "one", data: { ... } } } } )
```

Comment: So doc 1 and doc 2 are in the same collection. I have no problem writing a query to pick up a specific document. However, grabbing the embedded document is what I'm after.

Suppose I'm after the service 'two' object in doc 1. How could I write a query that just gives me this?


   { service: 'two', data: {...} }

Comment: You need to "project" the services field. Try coll.find({},{services:1})

Comment: And although you can query sub-fields with {"services.0":{..}}, you cannot "project" sub-fields at the current mongodb implementation.